# Why comparing current props vs nextProps having same value returns false?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I have a component that is receiving same props always.When I compare them in `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle,it returns false

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
  if(this.props === nextProps){return false;} //returns false
  else return true;
}
```

However If I compare current vs previous state having same value,they work fine and return true

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
      if(this.state === nextState){return false;}
      else return true; //return true
}
```

Both state and props are objects(reference type) but why they are behaving differently?

Comment: You are not comparing *by value*, you are comparing *by reference*

Comment: then why its giving true when I compare state which is also reference type?

Comment: I think you should only use `shouldComponentUpdate()` for a deep `prop or State` object and match something like `this.props.<some_object_key> === nextProps.<some_object_key>` without just reference comparison `(this.props=== nextProps)` (from  @DavinTryon 's comment )

Comment: @Shaheryarahmed props are by default immutable in react. But state is recommended to be immutable https://stackoverflow.com/a/47471276/6727189

Comment: @Shaheryarahmed if no state transition has occurred, React *might* use the same state object, so the references are the same.  But in order to *always* detect changes, you must use deep compare.

Comment: @David Tryon do you want to say,this.props and nextProps are entirely different objects(different reference),whereas this.state and nextState are same objects (same reference)??